# Expectation value of an operator

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, operators, hilbert-space

Suppose we have:
$$
\hat{Q}|\psi_1\rangle=q_1|\psi_1\rangle \\
\hat{Q}|\psi_2\rangle=q_2|\psi_2\rangle
$$
with $q_1 \neq q_2$.
Then consider the state:
$$
|\Psi\rangle=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(|\psi_1\rangle-i|\psi_2\rangle)
$$
I want to calculate the uncertainty in $\hat{Q}$. Then first we must compute $\langle\hat{Q^2}\rangle$ and $\langle\hat{Q}\rangle^2$. I started with $\langle\hat{Q^2}\rangle$. First,
$$
\hat{Q}|\Psi\rangle=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(q_1|\psi_1\rangle-iq_2|\psi_2\rangle)
$$
Then:
$$
\langle\Psi|\hat{Q}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(q_1^{*}\langle\psi_1|+iq_2^{*}\langle\psi_2|)
$$
It follows that:
$$
\langle\Psi|\hat{Q^2}|\Psi\rangle = (\langle\Psi|\hat{Q})(\hat{Q}|\Psi\rangle)
=\frac{1}{2}(q_1^{*}\langle \psi_1|+iq_2^{*}\langle \psi_2|)(q_1|\psi_1\rangle -iq_2|\psi_2\rangle )
$$
Using the fact that:
$$
\langle A|bB+cC\rangle = b\langle A|B\rangle + c\langle A|C\rangle \text{ and}\\
\langle bB+cC|A\rangle = b^{*}\langle B|A\rangle + c^{*}\langle C|A\rangle
$$
I found:
$$
\langle\Psi|\hat{Q^2}|\Psi\rangle = \frac{1}{2}(q_1^2-q_2 q_2^{*})
$$
Note that $q_1^2 \neq |q_1|^2$.
On the other hand, if I act on the ket vector twice to compute $\hat{Q^2}|\Psi\rangle$ I find:
$$
\hat{Q^2}|\Psi\rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(q_1^2|\psi_1\rangle -iq_2^2|\psi_2\rangle)
$$
Then using this expression to compute $\langle\Psi|\hat{Q^2}|\Psi\rangle$ yields:
$$
\langle\Psi|\hat{Q^2}|\Psi\rangle = \frac{1}{2}(q_1^2 - q_2^2)
$$
Now using the representation in the basis:
$$
\hat{Q}|\Psi\rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}
\left[\begin{matrix}q_1 \\ -iq_2\end{matrix}\right] \\
\langle\Psi|\hat{Q} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}[q_1^{*} \text{    }iq_2^{*}]
$$
Which gives:
$$
\langle\Psi|\hat{Q^2}|\Psi\rangle = q_1^{*}q_1 + q_2^{*}q_2
$$
Why am I getting different results?

Comment: Notice that $\left \langle a \psi + b \phi \right| \neq a\left\langle\psi\right| + b\left\langle\phi\right|$, since $\left\langle a\psi\right| = \left| a \psi \right\rangle^\dagger = (a\left|\psi\right\rangle)^\dagger = a^*\left\langle\psi\right| $.

Comment: Is $\hat{Q}$ Hermitian?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming $|\psi_1\rangle$ and $|\psi_2\rangle$ are orthonormal, your equation after you write "I found" is incorrect, it should be
\begin{align}
  (\langle \Psi|\hat Q)(\hat Q|\Psi\rangle) 
&= \frac{1}{2}\Big(q_1^*q_1\langle\psi_1|\psi_1\rangle - i q_1^*q_2 \langle\psi_1|\psi_2\rangle +iq_2^*q_1\langle\psi_2|\psi_1\rangle -i^2q_2^*q_2\langle\psi_2|\psi_2\rangle\Big) \\
&= \frac{1}{2}(|q_1|^2+|q_2|^2)
\end{align}

Comment: Does this follow from:
$\frac{1}{2}(\langle q_1^{*}\psi_1+i q_2^{*}\psi_2|q_1\psi_1-iq_2\psi_2\rangle)$?

Comment: @Ali Yes; just use the properties of the inner product that you wrote down, and you'll get precisely that.  The cross terms cancel due to orthogonality of $|\psi_1\rangle$ and $|\psi_2\rangle$.

Comment: Did you assume that $\langle A+B|C+D\rangle=\langle A|B \rangle+\langle A|D \rangle +\langle B |C \rangle+\langle B|D \rangle$? Because I can get to what you posted if I use this. But I can't see why this is true.

Comment: @Ali Yes (but the first term on the right should be $\langle A|C\rangle$).  You can prove that by applying the inner product properties you wrote down twice, once for the first "slot" and once for the second "slot."

Comment: But in the first term, for example, I have $\langle q_1^{*}\psi_1|q_1\psi_1\rangle$. But $\langle aA|B \rangle = a^{*}\langle A|B\rangle$ and $\langle A|bB \rangle = b\langle A|B\rangle$, so I get $q_1^2\langle \psi_1|\psi\rangle_1$, which is different from what you posted.

Comment: @Ali Not quite.  In the notation you're using in the comments, the first term is $\langle q_1 \psi_1|q_1\psi_1\rangle = q_1^*q_1\langle\psi_1|\psi_1\rangle$.

Comment: Now I am confused. Why is this the case? Sorry...

Comment: @Ali It seems your confusion stems from mixing legitimate bra-ket notation with inner product notation used more commonly in mathematics.  In legit bra-ket notation, $|\psi\rangle$ is a vector, the $\psi$ inside is just a label, and $\langle\psi|$ is a corresponding dual vector.  In mathy notation, $\psi$ is a vector, the symbol $|\psi\rangle$ has no independent meaning, and $\langle \psi|\phi\rangle$ is the inner product of two vectors $\psi$ and $\phi$.  I'd recommending reading up on this stuff; this might help: http://physics.stackexchange.com/a/57793/19976

Comment: @Ali Sure thing.